# Cannot use import statement outside a module using nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use vue-agile carousel, I can install and get it to run without any issues right after i install it, i am using NUXT, but after restarting my server i keep getting this error and can not find any solution for it

```
<template>
  <div>
    <agile>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="/img/img2.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="/img/img1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </agile>
  </div>
</template>
<script >
import { VueAgile } from "vue-agile";
export default {
  name: "",
  layout: "",
  middleware: [],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  components: {
    agile: VueAgile,
  },
  
};
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

Did you checked the documentation about [how to use this plugin in Nuxt](https://github.com/lukaszflorczak/vue-agile#nuxtjs--ssr-support) instead of a regular Vue?

**plugins/vue-agile.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAgile from 'vue-agile'

Vue.use(VueAgile)
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
    plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-agile', mode: 'client']
}
```

To use component without SSR use the `client-only` component:

```
<client-only placeholder="Loading...">
    <agile>...</agile>
</client-only>
```

**EDIT**: Add Shreerang's suggestion (comment below).

Comment: I get the same error message. and added a new pic to my question

Comment: That warning in the new screenshot is because you are using Typescript, and that node_module is not ready for I guess, but I don't think that is a problem. I found a possible solution, other people reported that maybe this can happen when you update the Node version but you don't update your node_modules after that, so maybe you can try this:`rm -rf node_modules && npm install` in your Nuxt root folder. Let me know if it helps, it sounds like magical I know haha.

Comment: Nope, still the same, and it s not just this modules, even the one I use to used before giving me the same error

Comment: can also be used here right? 
inside if(process.client) {...}

Answer (score 4):

from official Nuxt.js docs, they said.

> If you get an Cannot use import statement outside a module error, you
> may need to add your package to the build > transpile option in
> nuxt.config.js for webpack loader to make your plugin available.

Example

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    transpile: ['vue-agile']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sergio's answer above is mostly accurate, but needs a small tweek.

The `nuxt.config.json` config needs the following update. No `build` config is required.

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-agile', mode: 'client' }
]
```

Comment: Sure, the error seems to be in the server side, I changed my answer to include this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark `vue-agile` to be transpiled in order to work on the server part (SSR).

`nuxt.config.js` :

```
...
  build: {
    transpile: [/vue-agile/]

  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type="module"` in your script tag

```
<script type="module">
import { VueAgile } from "vue-agile";
export default {
  name: "",
  layout: "",
  middleware: [],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  components: {
    agile: VueAgile,
  },
  
};
</script>
```

Comment: Same error , i think I tried that before. this is very frustrating.